# Finding segfaults without crashes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am working on a program that may have segfaults but it does not crash. Is there a specific way or method to check for segmentation faults that might occur but does not make the program crash.

Thank You.

Comment: If a seg-fault does not make the program crash, it means you've registered a handler for `SIGSEGV`.  Why not just disable that for the purpose of debugging?

Comment: I think it's more likely that the OP doesn't really mean "segfault" when they say "segfault".

Comment: I think he means _spurious memory writes_ and / or buffer overruns.

Comment: Sorry about that, yeah basically something is being outputted that is not being cleared out correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find illegal memory accesses that *don't* result in crashes, Valgrind ( http://valgrind.org/ ) is a good tool.